# Basic question about floor function and limit ( $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \lfloor{x-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{x+3}\rfloor$)

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification

> $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \lfloor{x-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{x+3}\rfloor$
>
> calculate the limit if it exists if not then prove it does not exist

---

I tried approaching by squeeze theorem and floor function property and got

$(x-2) \cdot (x+3)-1<\lfloor{x-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{x+3}\rfloor \leq (x-2) \cdot (x+3)$

but then if I calculate the limits as $x$ approaches zero I get
$-7<\lfloor{x-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{x+3}\rfloor \leq-6$

which did not give me an answer according to squeeze theorem so I tried a different approach by side limits

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \lfloor{x-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{x+3}\rfloor = \lfloor{0-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{0+3}\rfloor = -6$

and $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^-} \lfloor{x-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{x+3}\rfloor = \lfloor{-1-2}\rfloor \cdot \lfloor{-1+3}\rfloor = -6$

so the limit exists and $L=-6$
is this correct? is there a different way?
thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $x$ approaches $0$ from **above** (i.e. the right side limit), you have that

$\lfloor x-2\rfloor~$ **stays** at $~-2~$ and 
$\lfloor x+3\rfloor~$ **stays** at $~3.~$ 
Therefore, the product **stays** at $~-6.~$

As $x$ approaches $0$ from **below** (i.e. the left side limit), you have that

$\lfloor x-2\rfloor~$ **stays** at $~-3~$ and 
$\lfloor x+3\rfloor~$ **stays** at $~2.~$ 
Therefore, the product **stays** at $~-6.~$

So, the limit, as $x$ approaches $0$ from above does in fact equal the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from below, and this limit is $-6.$

---

What makes this problem unusual is that you have the limit of the product of two functions, $~\lfloor x-2\rfloor~$ and $~\lfloor x+3\rfloor,~$ where for each function, as $x$ approaches $0$, the left side limit of the function is not equal to the right side limit of the function.

Despite that, when examining the product of the two functions, as $x$ approaches $0$, the left side limit of the product does equal the right side limit of the product.

Comment: thank you ! just I did not understand if the limit does exist as x approaches 0 or not because the sides of the limit are not equal if we look at each function individually 
is it not continious?

Comment: @Adamrk Continuity is a totally different subject.  If you have a generic function $f(x)$ and if the (finite) limit $L$ exists of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$, then the function is continuous at $x=a$ if and only if $L = f(a)$.  When **merely** checking whether the limit exists, no consideration is given about $f(a)$ itself.  Suppose that the left hand limit of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $a$ is (finite) $M$, and the right hand limit is (finite) $N$.  Then, the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ exists, if and only if $M = N.$

Answer (score 2):

$x+2 < \lfloor x+3\rfloor\leq x+3$ and $ x-3<\lfloor x-2 \rfloor\leq x-2$.

this implies $(x+2).(x-3)<\lfloor x+3 \rfloor.\lfloor x-2 \rfloor\leq (x+3).(x-2)$

so $lim_{x \to 0}(x+2).(x-3)<lim_{x \to 0}\lfloor x+3 \rfloor.\lfloor x-2 \rfloor\leq lim_{x \to 0} (x+3).(x-2)$

$\Rightarrow $$lim_{x \to 0}\lfloor x+3 \rfloor.\lfloor x-2 \rfloor=-6.$

**warning : the first implication is not necessary true because if the both left sides are negative   and the other are positive maybe in one case we must reverse the product of sides  ,but any way in all cases it will get the same limit $-6$**.so try to  rewrite the complete proof by yourself .